# Как инициализировать tomcat pool в spring правильнее?

Tags: spring, tomcat, pool

Я знаю о нескольких способах инициализации.

Какой из них использовать *правильнее* всего и чем они *отличаются*?

#### Первый:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
      p:driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
      p:url="${database.url}"
      p:username="${database.username}"
      p:password="${database.password}"/>
```

#### Второй:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/project"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/tomcat.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
```

Интересует не то где и как инициализировать, а какой способ инициализации выбрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

наверно вам нужно сконфигурировать datasource бин

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public javax.sql.DataSource datasource() {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
}
```

Comment: Меня интересует какой из этих двух способов выбрать, а не то в какой конфигурации инициализировать этот бин. Я отобразил два способа как создать свой пул, но какой лучше не знаю.

Comment: Во втором случае вам надо публиковать класс на JNDI. Если вы используете спринг то нет в этом необходимости.